# Create database in oracle for manually created user

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to create the user and the database within that user. But when I tried to create database its giving the warning message as

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01501: CREATE DATABASE failed
ORA-01100: database already mounted
```

Then I tried

```
STARTUP NOMOUNT;
```

Its giving the warning message for insufficient privileges even I have given all the permission to that particular user.
Can any one please help in finding the solution for this?

Answer (score 6):

You don't create a database under a user in Oracle; I believe you're using terminology from another database poduct. The equivalent is [a schema, which is a logical container for a group of objects](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16508/intro.htm#CEGJFFFD). User and schema are essenentially synonymous in Oracle - when you create a user is automatically has its own schema.

You create the database once (which you already seem to have done, or had done for you), then create as many schemas/users as your application needs. You don't ever rerun the `create database` under normal circumstances - you certainly wouldn't as a normal user.

If you connect as that user you will be able to create tables, views, packages etc., assuming it has really been granted all the necessary privileges.

Comment: Ohh thanks, that means we can create schema, and user within that schema, after that we can create different DB objects, Am I right?

Comment: No, when you `create user`, that user automatically has a schema. They are the same thing. You don't create a schema separately. (There is a `create schema` command, but that doesn't do quite what you might think).